# Configure kube-proxy in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to configure kube-proxy in GKE?

I can see the pods creating from the daemonset, but I cannot see the daemonset itself.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

kube-proxy pod in k8s (not only in GKE) is created as [Static Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/).

Kubelet automatically creates so-called mirror pod on Kubernetes API server for each static pod, so the pods are visible there, but they cannot be controlled from the API server.[2](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/cluster-administration/static-pod/)

That's why you cannot edit and configure it as a usual API object.

However, you can edit kube-proxy manifest on the nodes and kubelet applies a new configuration.
Static pod manifest located on each node in

> /etc/kubernetes/manifests//etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.manifest

You can ssh into node and manually change it but we can automate it using cilium approach for removing kube-proxy[3](https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.9/gettingstarted/kubeproxy-free/) with DaemonSet and modify it a little bit[4](https://tech.griphone.co.jp/2020/08/06/cilium-kube-proxy-replacement/).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-proxy-configurator
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kube-proxy-configurator
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kube-proxy-configurator
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              echo 'Changing kube-proxy iptables-min-sync-period'

              sed -i 's/iptables-min-sync-period=10s/iptables-min-sync-period=2s/g' /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.manifest

              echo 'All Done!'

          image: alpine:latest
          name: kube-proxy-configurator
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes
              name: kubernetes-configs
      containers:
        - image: k8s.gcr.io/pause
          name: pause
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /etc/kubernetes
            type: Directory
          name: kubernetes-configs
```

Just apply it and kube-proxy configuration will be changed on each node (even on newly created by autoscaler).

```
kubectl apply -f kube-proxy-configurator.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

At the node level, the system is managed by Kubernetes K8s, whereas, at the master level, the system is [managed by GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview). The [master operates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture) and runs the Kubernetes API server, core resources controllers and the scheduler.

Even though the kube-proxy resides within the node, the cluster is responsible for the kube-proxy, and, please bear in mind that in GKE the cluster master is inaccessible.

While it is possible to [configure the proxy in Kubernetes k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/), it is not possible to do so in GKE.

For the daemonset, please make sure that you are looking through all namespaces.

```
$ kubectl get ds --all-namespaces
```